# Javascript, items persist in local storage after being removed

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm building a Phone Book where users are able to add, delete and search contacts. Everything works well so far, I can add and save contacts in local storage and I can delete them in the UI. But after deleting them, they still persist in the local storage, so they reappear when the page is refreshed. 
Any suggestion is welcome!

```js
// Contact class:

    class Contact {
      constructor(name, phone) {
     
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
      }   
    } 

// output

    static addContactToList(contact) {
    const itemDiv = document.querySelector('#contact-items');  
        const list = document.querySelector('#names');
      
        list.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", `
          </li>
          <li class="collection-item">
                
      <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user text-blue "></i><span class="text-grey">${contact.name} </span></a>
      
          <span class="contact-phone"><i class="fas fa-phone text-blue phi "><span class="text-grey ph">${contact.phone}</span></i></span>
             
     <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
     </li> `);
         
      }

//removeContact function in the Store class:

    static removeContact(phone) {
        const contacts = Store.getContact();
         
        contacts.forEach((contact, index) => {
       
          if(contact.phone === phone) {
            contacts.splice(index, 1);
          }
       
        });
     
        localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts));
      
      } 
    }

//call the method:

document.querySelector('#contact-items').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 
    
      Store.removeContact(e.target.parentElement);
      
      
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. What is your question?

Comment: it should work, can you add your code in codesandbox repo and paste so I can debug better

Comment: You should not splice(modify) an array while you are looping over it, you could possibly skip elements due to their indexes changing due to the modification. Might not see this if you are only ever removing one element, but if you ever try to remove more than one it will be noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
static removeContact(phone) {
    const contacts = Store.getContact();
    contacts = contacts.filter(c => contact.phone !== phone )
    localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(contacts));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. This doesn't work either . I still can't figure out where the code is broken..I keep looking for solutions.